Issue with going back to previous page on statamic antlers template
I'm having an issue with getting a link to work in an antlers template that should take me back to the previous url I was on.
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}">Back</a>

It seems to redirect back onto the same page I was on instead of going back to the one before so was wondering what I need to change to get it to go back to the previous url.
Tried
url()->previous()

as well as number of other potential solutions but nothing is working so far.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515636/redirect-two-pages-back-with-url-previous-in-laravel?rq=2

Are you using Antlers or Laravel Blade?

Using the Antlers template

So you can use Statamic with their own templating enging called Antlers, or with Laravel's templating engine Blade.

Antlers
When using Antlers you can use dynamic HTML (called Tags in Statamic) by using curly-braces {{ }}.
However, in Antlers their are 3 kinds of delimiters, namely;

{{ }} The basic and primary delimiter pair, used to render variables, evaluate expressions, call Tags, and do almost all core Antlers things.
{{? ?}} and {{$ $}} Allow you to write, execute, and echo PHP.
{{# #}} Are for code comments.


Antlers documentation.

You are using url()->previous(). url() is a Laravel helper, not an Antlers tag. So in order to use it in an Antlers template, you'd have to use one of the PHP delimiters as follows:

{{? url()->previous() ?}}
{{$ url()->previous() $}}.

I like to use the {{$ $}} version since that makes me immediately think of PHP, therefore I know I'm outputting PHP code.

Blade
When using Blade, {{ url()->previous() }} should work, so there must be something else wrong. Perhaps take a look at your log files, and make sure your template ends in the .blade.php file extension.
